# I can't add existing webparts to a page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm having a weird issue using Sharepoint.
I have created a site and added it's content database, it contains for example a webpart called Webpart1 on VisualStudio, as usual the Webpart is not shown since it can't be found. I deploy my Webparts project, reload the page and now I can see Wepart1 rendered. Everything normal.

But if I edit the page, go to Add -> Custom Webpart -> Webpart1 I recieve an error telling that the webpart can't be found or is not registered as safe.

I have checked all the settings and they seem to be correct, if not the webpart already on the page would be not shown, but it is, so if the webpart on the gallery is the same that is on the site, how can it not be found or registered as safe?
Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed the webpart from Visual Studio by pressing F5(debugging) it will retract the solution when you stop debugging the project. Try right clicking the project and select Deploy. Then you should be able to go to the side and edit page and add the web part.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but sadly any of those things work. I retracted and redeployed everything and I'm the same situation, I can see the webparts on my page but I can't edit the web and duplicate any of them.